# Show that the sequence $\left\{ x^n \right\}$ of functions converges uniformly on $[0,k],k<1$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Show that the sequence of functions $\left\{ x^n \right\}$  converges uniformly on $[0,k],k<1$, but non-uniformly on $[0,1]$.

For $x\in[0,1)$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}x^n=0$$ 
and for $x=1$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=1.$$

Therefore, the limit function is 
$$f(x)=\cases{
0 &$\quad 0\leq x <1$\\
1 &$\quad x=1$}$$ 
Let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary. Then, for each $x\in (0,1)$ 
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon\implies x^n<\epsilon \implies n\ln x<\ln\epsilon \implies n>\frac{\ln\epsilon}{\ln x}$$
For $x=0,1$ 
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0<\epsilon,\quad\forall n\geq1
$$
Choose a natural number $N(\epsilon,x)=\left[\frac{\ln\epsilon}{\ln x}\right]+1$ Here $[\cdot]$ is the box function.

Note that $N(\epsilon,x)\to +\infty$ as $x\to 1^-$. So, $N(\epsilon,x)$ is not bounded on $[0,1]$.

Hence, the convergence of $\left\{ x^n \right\}$ is not uniform on $[0,1]$.

I faced problems in showing uniform convergence of $\left\{ x^n \right\}$ on $[0,k]$, $k<1$.

Comment: You can use `$\epsilon$` or `$\varepsilon$`; using `$\in$` is rather unusual; compare $\epsilon$ or $\varepsilon$; and $\in$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon>0$ take $n_0$ such that $k^{n_0} <\varepsilon$. As $x<k<1$, we have
\begin{equation}
|x^n-0|=|x^n|<|k^{n}|<|k^{n_0}|<\varepsilon \quad \forall x \in[0,k], \forall n\ge n_0.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Hint: given $\epsilon > 0$, find $n$ such that $k^n < \epsilon$.